# how to search through a String collection for a match of 3 characters or more

Tags: java, search, collections

I'm trying to make an application that can search through a collection of names and return ones the come close to the one that you searched for. Example : jos is searched and jose,josie and josh are all returned in a JList.

here's my code which i'm using as a prototype :

```
public class Window {

private JPanel pan;
private String[] names1 = {"lewis","joe","jack","ryan","kane","google","brooke"};
private LinkedList<String> names;
private String[] name;
private JTextField enterbar;
private JButton btn;
private JTextField enterbar2;
private JButton btn2;

public Window(){

    enterbar = new JTextField(10);
    btn = new JButton("enter");
    enterbar2 = new JTextField(10);
    btn2 = new JButton("Add");


    names = new LinkedList<String>();
    names.add("rose");
    pan = new JPanel();
    Font f1 = new Font("ariel", 0 , 20);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Contact Saver");
    DefaultListModel v = new DefaultListModel();
    v.addElement(names);
    JList list = new JList(v);

    list.setVisibleRowCount(4);//sets how many elements you can see and if    there is more it adds a scroll bar
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);//makes it so you can only select one element at a time
    list.setFixedCellWidth(600);
    list.setFixedCellHeight(30);
    list.setFont(f1);

    frame.add(enterbar);
    frame.add(btn);
    frame.add(enterbar2);
    frame.add(btn2);
    pan.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    frame.add(pan);//adds a scroll bar to the list

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(700,500);     
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("here");
        }
    });
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            v.clear();
            if(names.contains(enterbar.getText().toLowerCase()))System.out.println("here");

            for(int i =0; i < names.size();i++){
            v.addElement(names.get(i));
        }
            System.out.println(v);
        }

    });

    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            v.clear();
            names.add(enterbar2.getText());
            for(int i =0; i < names.size();i++){
                v.addElement(names.get(i));
            }
        }

    });

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Window();
}

}
```

Comment: So what do u want to ask?

Comment: @minigeek how can I search through my collection of names and find the ones that have a common sequence of characters

Answer (score 0):

Create an implementation of the Levenshtein distance formula, as your loop through your list, assign a distance value to each one and return the lowest *n* values.

Answer (score 0):

You can read find() method in detail . Find () finds out the substring in the given array of string for reference see the sample :

```
 1:Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
 2:Pattern.matcher("0a1b1c3d4"); 
 3:int count = 0; 
 4:while(matcher.find())
 { 
 5:count++;
 }
```